# WooCommerce hooks ( Новый заказ)

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Есть задача - создание плагина для WooCommerce. Это первый опыт и по этому возникают вопросы.

Я повесил на хук создания нового заказа свою функцию. (её функционал пока неважен). Как мне можно удостовериться, что хук сработал? И вообще, тот ли хук я использую?

```
function send_message_on_new_order() {
$user_option = get_option('webcom_menu_page_connect');
$login = $user_option['connect_login'];
$auth_key = $user_option['connect_auth_key'];
$admin_phone = $user_option['admin_phone'];
$sender = $user_option['connect_sender'];
$text = $user_option['admin_message'];

sendMessage($admin_phone, $text, $login, $sender, $auth_key);
echo '<script>alert(1212);</script>';
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_new_order', 'send_message_on_new_order',  1, 1  );
```

Answer (score 2):

Хук используете правильный.

Для контроля можно выводить сообщение в лог-файл с помощью php. echo со скриптом плохо само по себе, но кроме того, сработает у клиента, а не у вас.

Comment: Echo стоит на время разработки)
Решил проблему вот так:
add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', 'send_message_on_new_order',  111, 1  );

Comment: Я вам указал на то, что оно и во время разработки имеет нулевой смысл. А задачу вы решили другую.